# How to change the font type of the labels in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to shift font types in my figures. While the font type can be changed in ordinary ggplot objects with ease, I can't change the font for the labels in ggarrange.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggpubr)

# get base plot in Times New Roman
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text = element_text(family = 'serif'))

# make two barplots
bp1 <- g + geom_bar()
bp2 <- g + geom_bar(aes(weight = displ))

# arrange barplots in grid
ggarrange(bp1, bp2,
          labels = 'auto',
          ncol = 1,
          nrow = 2)
```

According to the documentation, there is the `font.labels` parameter with an optional `family`-argument. So I tried `font.labels = list(family = 'serif')` as an argument to `ggarrange` but that didn't work. It said:

```
Warning message:
In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.
```

How can I change the labels of `ggarrange` to match with the font in the plot?

Comment: It is a typo... try `font.label = list(family = "serif")`. There is no s.

Comment: Ah I see now! Thanks. I guess the confusion was that the other parameter is spelled as `labels`

Comment: No worries, it happesn. Feel free to close this questino.

Comment: Is there a difference between closing and deleting btw?

Comment: Yes, better to close, for future users having the same error because of typo.